# Lists plugin in TinyMCE failing to initialize after update to v5

Tags: plugins, tinymce

After updating to version 5 of TinyMCE from version 4 (mostly to fix an error with the color picker in version 4), the `lists` plugin stops working.

Initially, I tried creating custom buttons for the `numlist` and `bullist`, but that shouldn't be necessary since the plugin should handle that.

This is my initalization block:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    forced_root_block: 'div',
    plugins: 'lists',
    toolbar: 'fontselect | fontsizeselect | undo redo | bold italic underline forecolor | numlist bullist | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify',
    invalid_elements: 'script',
});
```

An error appears that says "Failed to initialize plugin: lists" and the console reports that `Failed to initialize plugin: lists Error: "editor.addButton has been removed in tinymce 5x, use editor.ui.registry.addButton or editor.ui.registry.addToggleButton or editor.ui.registry.addSplitButton instead"`

I looked in the code for the lists plugin, and every instance of `addButton` or similar was accompanied with `ui.registry`, so I don't understand where it's getting an `editor.addButton` command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure that you are not still loading the old TinyMCE 4 plugin for lists?  That error message would imply that the list plugin is trying to use an old TinyMCE 4 API to do something but the plugins we ship with TinyMCE 5 would not do that.  Perhaps you have a caching issue?

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I have no idea how, considering that I disabled caching on Firefox and did a hard reload on the page several times. Only by opening the file and doing a hard reload did it finally realize that there was a newer version available.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would stop this from affecting my users once I deploy it? How do I tell returning users that they need to do a hard-reload? Is there a way that I can do this programmatically from the server?

Comment: @ChrisFox caching is a large topic so its hard to say exactly how you could address.  One approach would be the change the folder that contains TinyMCE so the path is no longer the same (e.g. tinymce5010 vs tinymce5016 ).  If the path changes the old cached data won't be used as the path changes.

Comment: That worked a treat, @MichaelFromin Simple, but effective - thanks.